Decoding an Image with SkiaSharp Results in 90% Black Image
As described in this question, I'm working with the Fortnite API to retrieve an image of their map and some coordinates to place a point on that map. Here's the map image, for reference. As shown in the previous question as well, the coordinate mapping problem was solved, but I was using System.Drawing. I deployed to a Linux box and that didn't work, so now I'm trying to rewrite it with SkiaSharp.
Here's my first attempt at it:
using var httpClient = new HttpClient();
await using var stream = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(mapLocations.Images.Blank.AbsoluteUri);
var bitmap = SKBitmap.Decode(stream);
// the problem appears to happen here^

The problem here is that, for some reason, I get only part of the map image at the top (the blue section) but the rest of the image is black. It looks sort of like it didn't fully download or something like that. Am I missing something?
Here's a link to the full file this code is in, in case that helps provide any extra context.


Have you saved the downloaded image to confirm that that part works as it is supposed to?

@JonasH Yes, I tried commenting out the drawing logic and just saving the image as-is and it still shows up as above.

If you are sure the drawing code is not at fault, you should probably remove it from the example. I would also save the stream directly to file, that should tell you if the problem is with SkiaSharp or with the image download.

@JonasH Edited the response to narrow it down. The file download works just fine, it's the decode that causes the issue (I did try saving to a file before and after the decode).

FYI: Don't BOTH save a stream to a file AND call SKBitmap.Decode. To use a stream twice, need to have a stream subclass that supports stream.Position = 0;. It does surprise me that SKBitmap.Decode failed to work correctly with the stream. That would be a bug in Decode. I agree that the symptom suggests the image is not fully downloaded yet. I suspect Decode incorrectly assumes the stream is fully downloaded at the moment it is called. That would be an incorrect assumption on its part.

So it turns out it was an issue with how SKBitmap.Decode(stream); was handling the stream. I had to set stream.Position = 0;, but because a regular Stream doesn't support that, I had to first copy it to a MemoryStream. Here's what I ended up with:
    using var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    await using var stream = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(mapLocations.Images.POIs.AbsoluteUri);
    await using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    await stream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
    memoryStream.Position = 0;
    return SKBitmap.Decode(memoryStream);

I'd definitely be interested in hearing if there are better ways to handle this, but this worked for me in this case.

in your IDE hover "stream" and see what type it is being inferred as.  You may be able to define it as a concrete stream type instead of "var stream" and this may give you access to resetting the stream position before passing it to your Decode method.

It's a System.IO.Stream that it infers. But I don't think I can just pick another Stream type, unless you have a specific one in mind?

You could try changing lines 2-4 to 'await using MemoryStream memoryStream = await httpClient' then reposition. It may save you reading to one stream type, then having to copy.

@Kevin - that won't compile. AFAIK, the code in answer is what needs to be done. Apparently Decode incorrectly handles a stream that is not yet fully downloaded.

This answer is a good approach. Copying to MemoryStream ensures the stream is fully downloaded, before Decode is called. Decode is a synchronous operation. Ideally, SkiaSharp would add a new method public async Task<SKBitmap> SKBitmap.DecodeAsync(Stream stream) that can handle an asynchronous stream that takes time to download. Until that exists, I would do exactly what this answer does.
